# jQuery validate except some selected characters

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to create a validator.

The validator needs to reject only two characters which is only `" ,` and accept rest of them.

Here is my present code

```
<input type="text"/>​

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(str) { alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease except.'); return ''; } ) );
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/ntywf/324/)**

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, but what is wrong with using [",] instead of [^a-zA-Z0-9] ?

Comment: @jJ' Validator can accept except those two characters. I don't how to do that :(

Comment: that is how I understood that [",] means match these two characters (",) and call the function; [^",] would be the opposite - match all characters except these two (",)

Comment: @jJ' could you help me for that, I'm just beginner :(

Comment: just change [^a-zA-Z0-9] in your code to [",]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ntywf/325/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if ((/[\"\,]/g).test($th.val())==true) 
        {

                $th.val( $th.val( ).replace(/[\"\,]/g,function(str) { alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease except.');return '';} )) ;
        }
    });
});​
```